# How to use slist from STL?

Tags: c++, stl, linked-list

I am new to STL. I found out that `slist` (the singly linked link list) is not a part of standard C++ standard. So how to use it in my programs?

I downloaded the [slist.h](http://www.sgi.com/tech/stl/Slist.html) and pasted in

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 9.0\VC\include
```

but it is asking for `algobase.h` and other header files (`alloc.h`, `stl_slist.h`) which I could not find in the include folder of VS9 or windows SDK. How to go about it? please help.

Comment: http://kera.name/articles/2010/08/it-is-not-called-the-stl-mmkay/

Comment: why don't you just use std::list?

Comment: The following may help you in writing better questions: [English capitalization](http://www.grammar.net/capitalization), [ellipsis](http://grammar.ccc.commnet.edu/grammar/marks/ellipsis.htm), [usage of space around parentheses](http://english.stackexchange.com/q/5987/14369) and [space after comma](http://www.englishclub.com/writing/punctuation-comma.htm).

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The container is called [`std::forward_list`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/forward_list). It's part of the new standard library.

Comment: is it in c++11.0??..i am using Qt using vs2009 compiler which i think is not c++11.0 compatible...only vs11 and vs12 is c++11.0 compatible and Qt in mine is supporting VS9 VS10...i can use a list for the purpose...but i dont wanna use more memory for real time image processing algo implementation..what to do??plz help....

Comment: Check your compiler documentation for library extensions; I'm pretty sure that VS9 would come with a singly-linked list somewhere...

Comment: can any one tel me how to integrate the latest STL with vs9..i downloaded the latest from http://www.sgi.com/tech/stl/download.html ..i read it says all the files are headers and no need to link to any library...i downloaded the entire STL 3.3 v...included the path to my header file path...but again some compile error...its so confusing..